# How to do ssh in a bash script with lot of commands?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I tried to run the following command in a bash script but only till ./install.sh rereplica is called . Rest of the commands are not called at all.

```
  ssh $node2user@$node2 "cd /tmp; tar -xf $mmCS.tar; cd $mmCS; ./install.sh csreplica; ./install.sh keepalived $vip low;./install.sh haproxy $node1:8080 $node2:8080 $vip:8080; ./install.sh confmongo $dbPath"
```

Comment: Interesting since `rereplica` isn't anywhere in the example you gave us.

Comment: this is argument to the script which does some configuration.This is executed successfully. I checked.

Comment: Does your `install.sh` do an `exit` at the end?

Comment: no, it does not do exit.

Comment: @arco444: Shouldn't matter since he doesn't `source` it.

Comment: If I  break the statement in two parts then it works fine.       ssh $node2user@$node2 "cd /tmp; tar -xf $mmCS.tar; cd $mmCS; ./install.sh csreplica" AND ssh $node2user@$node2 " cd/tmp/$mmCS; ./install.sh keepalived $vip low;./install.sh haproxy $node1:8080 $node2:8080 $vip:8080; ./install.sh confmongo $dbPath"

Comment: Try to add `set -x;` at the beginning. That will make the remote shell print the commands as they are executed. That might give you a hint.

Comment: do u mean at the begining of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do execute a complex script using SSH, I usually write a script locally, copy it on the target machine with SSH and then execute it there:

```
scp foo.sh $node2user@$node2:
ssh $node2user@$node2 "bash ./foo.sh"
```

That way, I can debug the script simply by invoking it with `bash -x` and I can use the full power of BASH.

Alternatively, you can use

```
ssh $node2user@$node2 "set +x; cd /tmp; ..."
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I have done scp of install.sh to remote machine and running the script with different arguments. Only this "bash" before ./install.sh $vip low ( or, in ur example , ./foo.sh ), I am not giving. Should I put this ? what does that do ?

Comment: There are different types of shells on *nix systems, it specifies that the script shall be executed with `bash`.

Comment: @prashantas: You're not doing the same thing. Executing a list of commands separated with `;` isn't the same as putting them into a script file and executing that: There won't be any surprises with quotes parsing, you can easily put debug output between commands, you can see the code much better, ...

Comment: actually set -x helped me. I was doing pkill -f mongo and pkill -f tomcat . That was doing something unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `ssh` a script on standard input:

```
ssh $node2user@$node2 < my_script.sh
```